# Azure Data Factory from Cosmos documents to Blob files

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

Want to use Azure Data Factory to pull Cosmos documents and copy each document to file (blob) in Storage where the file name == document id with file suffix == json.  E.g. document content `{ id: "0001", name: "gary" }`would be a blob named `0001.json` with the same content `{ id: "0001", name: "gary" }`.

Hava a Cosmos dataset targeting a Cosmos collection of JSON documents.  Plus a Blob Storage dataset with an absolute file path (container + file name).  Using a **Copy Data** activity in a pipeline the setup is vanilla with source == Cosmos dataset (no schema) and sink == Blob dataset (no schema) creating a single blob line-delimited per Cosmos document.

Guessing that a **Lookup** to a **ForEach** with a **Copy Data** activity would be right.  **Lookup** against the Cosmos dataset should yield items (collection of JSON documents).  **ForEach** settings ought to be **Sequential** and something like **items** == `@activity('Find').output.value.id` where **Find** is the name of the **Lookup** step.  The **items** expression is probably way off (help here).  Choosing an activity for the **ForEach** is the big question.  Can **Copy Data** be bent to act on each item of the **ForEach** (only datasets available for the source + sink)?

Comment: Right now, the only thing that works is a LookUp on a Cosmos Dataset with no parameters and a query == `select c.id, c.version from c` piped to a ForEach with Items == `@activity('Find').output.value` and with a Copy Data activity where the Source goes back to the Cosmos Dataset with a dynamic content query `select * from c where c.id = "@{item().Id}" and c.version = @{item().Version}` before sinking to a Blob Dataset.  The LookUp gets identifies and the Copy Data the document by identifier.  Not too efficient but no idea however to use the `item` as a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

> Can Copy Data be bent to act on each item of the ForEach (only
> datasets available for the source + sink)?

Yes, Copy activity can be use in **ForEach** activity, you just need to keep the Sink Dataset filename as dynamic. You can create a parameter and assign its's value equal to `@activity('Find').output.value.id` so that it will get new filename every time.

There is a same case scenario explained in third-party tutorial by [sqlkover.com](https://sqlkover.com/dynamic-datasets-in-azure-data-factory/). You can refer this for better understanding.

Comment: Utkarsh, see my comment above.